# SQLite best three times for men and women for each race distance

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, window-functions, row-number

I started with this simple query that gives me the three men with the best times (1st, 2nd and 3rd) on the 125km race.

```
SELECT *
FROM Coureurs
WHERE Genre=’M’ AND Epreuve='125km' AND TempsPassage IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TempsPassage
LIMIT 3;
```

However, I would also need the three women (genre=F) with the best time on that distance.
AND the best three men and three women for each of the other distances (TempsPassage=80km/65km/40km,..).

This is way past my level... and I really want to avoid building separate "hardcoded" queries.
Thanks in advance,
Pierre

Comment: Is it supposed to be "Epreuve" =80km/65km/40km, and TempsPassage is the elapsed time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank the results for each race/genre and then filter to return only the rankings 1-3:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Epreuve, Genre ORDER BY TempsPassage) rn
  FROM Coureurs
  WHERE TempsPassage IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY (Epreuve + 0), Genre, rn
```

If there is a case of ties then maybe try `RANK()` window function instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. There won't be any ties because these are checkpoint times, all captured by QR code from the same android mobile (using system date/time). I changed the last line to  ORDER BY Epreuve, Genre, rn to have 1st,2nd,3rd women for the 125km together, then all three men for the 125km together, etc.  This solution has the benefit of not having to code the actual race distances in the query as these may be variable. For example, some checkpoints will handle the 40km and the 20km, while others will handle the 125,80 and 65kms. Perfect, thank you!

Comment: @PierreTremblay in the `ORDER BY` clause I use `Epreuve + 0` instead of just `Epreuve` because, as I see in your question, the values in the column `Epreuve` are strings and not numbers. So for a query of all the races `ORDER BY Epreuve` will return the races in an alphabetical order: '125km', '40km', '65km', '80km', but `ORDER BY (Epreuve + 0)` will convert implicitly the strings to numbers and the order will be numerical: '40km', '65km', '80km', '125km'.

Comment: But with Epreuve + 0, the order is: 1st woman 125km, 1st woman 65km, 1st woman 80km, then 2nd woman 125km, 2nd woman 65km, 2nd woman 80km, etc... followed by the same order for men. With just Epreuve, I get 1F-2F-3F-1M-2M-3M for the 125km, then the same order for the 65km, then the 80km. I really don't mind that the races are not listed in order but of course it would be great if you can do it. Thanks.

Comment: @PierreTremblay `ORDER BY (Epreuve + 0), Genre, rn` sorts first by `Epreuve` numerically, then by Genre and then by rn. Meaning you will have the 1st 6 rows for '40km', in which the first 3 rows will be for 'F' and the next 3 rows for 'M'. Then you will have 6 rows for '65km' , in which the first 3 rows will be for 'F' and the next 3 rows for 'M', and so on. I base all this to the data that is mentioned in your question.

Comment: @PierreTremblay Check this for the results of my query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e7160a8e9d1354839fce9540376833d5

Comment: Never mind, I think I found out why. Epreuve is actually prefixed with a 4-letter race identifier, for example "UTHC 125km" which is no doubt causing the sorting issue. Thank again for your great help.

Comment: @PierreTremblay Then if all rows of 125km have the same prefix use: `ORDER BY SUBSTR(Epreuve, 5) + 0, Genre, rn`

Comment: Hi. This solution has been working well on my Android 11 phone but I just found out that my app won't work on a phone that runs an older version. Apparently, the window function may not be supported (https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/6204001deb). Any way to modify the query to avoid the window function? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @PierreTremblay instead you can do it with a correlated subquery: `SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         (
           SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
           FROM Coureurs cc 
           WHERE cc.Epreuve = c.Epreuve AND cc.Genre = c.Genre AND cc.TempsPassage < c.TempsPassage
         ) rn
  FROM Coureurs c
  WHERE c.TempsPassage IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY (Epreuve + 0), Genre, rn`

Comment: Thank you! That solved the Android issue but I need a bit more help with the query. This returns all racers with no assigned time: SELECT Epreuve, rn, Sexe , Dossard, TempsPassage FROM (SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM Coureurs cc WHERE cc.Epreuve = c.Epreuve AND cc.Sexe = c.Sexe AND cc.TempsPassage < c.TempsPassage) rn FROM Coureurs c WHERE c.TempsPassage IS NOT NULL AND c.Statut IS "En_Course" ) WHERE rn <= 3 ORDER BY SUBSTR(Epreuve, 5) + 0 ASC, Sexe, rn; If I change cc.TempsPassage < ... to >, I get the last three/race/gender.

Comment: @PierreTremblay what do you mean by *no assigned time*? The condition `WHERE c.TempsPassage IS NOT NULL` makes sure that the resultset contains only non nulls.

Comment: Yes, that condition should work but is doesn't? Here are a few lines. The resultset contains all of the rows without an assigned TempsPassage.                                                    Epreuve     #  S  Dossard  Temps/Jour
----------  -  -  -------  ----------
UTHC 65km   1  F  6412
UTHC 65km   1  F  6413
UTHC 65km   1  F  6414
UTHC 65km   1  M  6404
UTHC 65km   1  M  6405
UTHC 65km   1  M  6406
UTHC 65km   1  M  6407.....

Comment: @PierreTremblay the condition `WHERE c.TempsPassage IS NOT NULL` is not possible to fail and return rows with null `TempsPassage`. Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27?

Comment: Here it is: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5c44aeb745cd3f6ba3d78bb873adda5a

Comment: @PierreTremblay you don't have nulls in the column `TempsPassage` but empty strings `''`. This is the 1st reason that you don't get correct results. The 2nd reason is that the dates are in the wrong format. In SQLite text dates should be in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Any other format is not comparable.

Comment: Thank you, I modified the query to check for non-empty strings in TempsPassage and changed the dates to the correct format but now the resultset is empty? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=919afc0899a04acd22dc45aaa7b5b3bf

Comment: @PierreTremblay since you did not change `''` to `null` you must check for empty dates inside the corelated subquery too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=483122f01f2a809c0db8a09e82cabd5c

Comment: Thank you so much. That's perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

Making the following assumptions/changes

- That the Epreuve colum is numeric (store 125, 80 .... instead of 125km, 80km ....)

  - 125km and 80km if sorted will see 80km being greater than 125km
  - the text values will cost a little in additional storage
  - It is easy to extract the value with km appended if need be e.g. `SELECT genre, Epreuve||'km', TempsPassage, Name FROM Coureurs`
- The the TempsPassage column stores the time (example uses seconds but see [Time Values](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values))

Assuming the following data :-

[image]

Also assuming that you want a relatively simple to understand single query then the following could suit :-

```
WITH
     m125 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'M' AND Epreuve = 125 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     f125 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'F' AND Epreuve = 125 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     m80 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'M' AND Epreuve = 80 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     f80 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'F' AND Epreuve = 80 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     m65 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'M' AND Epreuve = 65 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     f65 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'F' AND Epreuve = 65 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     m40 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'M' AND Epreuve = 40 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     f40 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'F' AND Epreuve = 40 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3)
SELECT * FROM m125 
    UNION SELECT * FROM f125
    UNION SELECT * FROM m80
    UNION SELECT * FROM f80
    UNION SELECT * FROM m65
    UNION SELECT * FROM f65
    UNION SELECT * FROM m40
    UNION SELECT * FROM f40
    ORDER BY Epreuve DESC,Genre DESC, TempsPassage ASC
;
```

This utilises what are called CTE's (Common Table Expressions), which are basically temporary tables.

- See [The WITH Clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html)

One CTE is used per permutation of Genre and Epreuve (2 * 4 = 8) it is built with a similar query.

Once all the CTE's are created the 8 separate temp tables are combined using UNION's.

Using the data above the result is (obviously you may want to sort the results differently) :-

[image]

The following is the SQL used to test the above and create the results :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Coureurs;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Coureurs (Genre TEXT, Epreuve int, TempsPassage int, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO Coureurs VALUES
    ('M',125,600,'Fred'),('M',125,610,'Bert'),('M',125,630,'Harry'),('M',125,620,'Albert'),('M',125,575,'David')
    
    ,('F',125,615,'Mary'),('F',125,625,'Anne'),('F',125,601,'Betty'),('F',125,625,'Sue'),('F',125,670,'Shelia')
    
    ,('F',80,450,'Louise'),('F',80,460,'Celia'),('F',80,425,'Debra'),('F',80,475,'Diana')
    
    ,('F',65,350,'Zara'),('F',65,360,'Yvonne'),('F',65,325,'Wilma'),('F',65,375,'Ursurla')
    
    ,('F',40,250,'Tracy'),('F',40,260,'Rhona'),('F',40,225,'Samantha'),('F',40,275,'Karen')
    
    ,('M',80,450,'Lou'),('M',80,460,'Colin'),('M',80,425,'Danny'),('M',80,475,'Eddy')
    
    ,('M',65,350,'Zed'),('M',65,360,'Mark'),('M',65,325,'William'),('M',65,375,'Tom')
    
    ,('M',40,250,'Jim'),('M',40,260,'Larry'),('M',40,225,'Peter'),('M',40,275,'Ronald')
;

SELECT * FROM Coureurs ORDER BY Random();
/* Easiest to understand - combining individual queries as CTE
    CTE = Common Table Expression (equates to temporary table) 
*/
WITH
     m125 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'M' AND Epreuve = 125 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     f125 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'F' AND Epreuve = 125 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     m80 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'M' AND Epreuve = 80 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     f80 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'F' AND Epreuve = 80 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     m65 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'M' AND Epreuve = 65 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     f65 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'F' AND Epreuve = 65 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     m40 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'M' AND Epreuve = 40 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3),
     f40 AS (SELECT * FROM Coureurs WHERE genre = 'F' AND Epreuve = 40 ORDER BY TempsPassage ASC LIMIT 3)
SELECT * FROM m125 
    UNION SELECT * FROM f125
    UNION SELECT * FROM m80
    UNION SELECT * FROM f80
    UNION SELECT * FROM m65
    UNION SELECT * FROM f65
    UNION SELECT * FROM m40
    UNION SELECT * FROM f40
    ORDER BY Epreuve DESC,Genre DESC, TempsPassage ASC
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Coureurs;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your solution Mike. I decided to go with the other solution that doesn't require knowing the various race distances.

Comment: I'm taking another look at your solution, and copied your code to try it out. When I run it with SQLite3, I get the following results which do not look right. Any advice? Thanks. M|125|600|Fred
F|40|275|Karen
F|80|450|Louise
F|80|460|Celia
F|40|250|Tracy
F|65|325|Wilma
M|125|575|David
F|125|670|Shelia
M|125|630|Harry
F|125|601|Betty
M|65|375|Tom
F|65|360|Yvonne
M|40|260|Larry
F|125|615|Mary
M|80|460|Colin
F|65|375|Ursurla
M|65|325|William
F|65|350|Zara
F|80|425|Debra
F|125|625|Sue
M|80|450|Lou
M|40|275|Ronald
M|80|475|Eddy
M|125|610|Bert
F|125|625|Anne
...

Comment: Looks as though you are looking at the results from the first select rather than the second.